# Comparing dictionaries with fewer loops

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has dictionaries as its values. Following is the structure of my dictionary

```
myD = {'key1': {'x' : 123, 'y' : 432},
       'key2': {'x' : 456, 'y' : 565},
       'key3': {'x' : 789, 'y' : 420},
       ...}
```

I need to compare the values of this dictionary ( as you can see I have similar dictionary structure in each value) and generate following output. Strategy is going through every dictionary in value field and select the minimum value for a given key and insert it into a new dictionary. As an example if we consider x key from the value dictionaries, it has `123` as the minimum. So my new dictionary should have `x:123`.

```
my_newD =  {'x' : 123, 'y' : 420, ...}
```

I can use 3 for loops to implement this, but is there any elegant way to do this with fewer for loops?

Answer (score 4):

I came up with two loops:

```
my_newD = {key: min(item[key] for item in myD.values()) 
           for key in  next(iter(myD.values()))}
```

EDIT: removed explicit dependence on the `'key1'` in the outer loop as suggested by @Andriy Makukha

EDIT 2: replaced `myD[list(myD.keys())[0]]` with `next(iter(myD.values()))`.
 Not sure which one is less cryptic but using `next` and `iter` does look more efficient.
Thanks to [Leo K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9962955/leo-k) for pointing it out!

Comment: This solution works faster than mine. Even though it assumes that all dictionaries inside main dictionary have same keys and requires `'key1'` to be present.

Comment: `my_newD = {key: min(item[key] for item in myD.values()) for key in myD[myD.keys()[0]]}` so that `key1` is not hardcoded.

Comment: @Andriy Makukha, yes, that would be better.

Comment: This solution has the same complexity as mine, i.e. O(m*n), but assumes keys are known from `key1`, which seems to be true in this case. Therefore, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Well, my solution is also O(m*n). How come everybody ignored the first correct answer? Go figure :)

Comment: myD[list(myD.keys())[0]] can be replaced with next(iter(myD.values())). On python3, this will work without creating a list of all the keys in myD - a lot faster, if the dict is large.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an O(n) solution using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myD = {'key1': {'x' : 123, 'y' : 432},
       'key2': {'x' : 456, 'y' : 565},
       'key3': {'x' : 789, 'y' : 420}}

# initialise defaultdict of lists
d = defaultdict(list)

# iterate input dictionary and add values to lists
for v1 in myD.values():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        d[k2].append(v2)

# calculate minimum
res = {k: min(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print(res)

{'x': 123, 'y': 420}
```

Comment: Two nested for, O(N) ? please explain, I could use some understanding :)

Comment: This is O(n) because you are only iterating each branch of the sub-dictionaries once. It's *impossible* to calculate the result without iterating all the data at least once.

Comment: Yeah, right. Still O(N^2) but I agree this is minimal

Comment: @Attersson, My `n` is number of subdictionary items. What's your `n`? If your `n` is the number of outer keys, I think you're misreading the problem.

Comment: Right. Since this dictionary is structured, we could name N = "number of elements" and M "width of element" and say this is O(M*N). Anyway, point made really.

Comment: @Attersson, Yes, that's a better way to put it. In any case, you can't get lower complexity than this.

Comment: Slightly faster than my solution but still slower than that of @taras.

Answer (score 1):

Two loops:

```
myD = {'key1': {'x' : 123, 'y' : 432},
       'key2': {'x' : 456, 'y' : 565},
       'key3': {'x' : 789, 'y' : 420}}

resD = {}
for key in myD:
    subD = myD[key]
    for k in subD:
        resD[k] = min(resD[k], subD[k]) if k in resD else subD[k]

print (resD)
```

Output:

```
{'x': 123, 'y': 420}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (better in terms of elegance) possibility with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
my_newD = pd.DataFrame(myD).min(axis=1).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in O(n)

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>>  min_t = lambda *t: [min(r) for r in zip(*t)]
>>> *_, min_vals = accumulate([v.values() for k,v in myD.items()], min_t)
>>> keys = next(iter(myD.values())).keys()
>>> dict(zip(keys, vals))
{'x': 123, 'y': 420}
>>>
```

**Explanation**

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> 
>>> myD = {'key1': {'x': 123, 'y': 432}, 'key2': {'x': 456, 'y': 565}, 'key3': {'x': 789, 'y': 420}}
>>> 
>>> # Define a func to find min of tuples
>>> def min_t(*t):
...     return [min(r) for r in zip(*t)]
... 
>>> # Build the tuple 
>>> t = (v.values() for k,v in myD.items())
>>> *_, min_vals = accumulate(t, min_t)
>>> min_vals
[123, 420]
>>> 
>>> keys = next(iter(myD.values())).keys()
>>> keys
dict_keys(['x', 'y'])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dict(zip(keys, vals))
{'x': 123, 'y': 420}
>>>
```

Or in a **one-liner**

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> from collections import deque
>>> dict(zip(next(iter(myD.values())).keys(), deque(accumulate((v.values() for k,v in myD.items()), lambda *t: [min(r) for r in zip(*t)]), maxlen=1).pop()))
{'x': 123, 'y': 420}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flat_d = [v[1] for v in myD.items()]

{"x":min([v["x"] for v in flat_d ]),"y":min([v["y"] for v in flat_d ])}
```

Answer (score 0):

This dynamic code works for **any number of variables**. Its complexity is O(M*N) where M=number of variables to find minimum of, and N = number of keys in `myD`

```
# here, M = 3, N = 3
myD = {'key1': {'x' : 123, 'y' : 432, 'z': 100},
       'key2': {'x' : 456, 'y' : 565, 'z': 99},
       'key3': {'x' : 789, 'y' : 420, 'z': 250}}
firstKey = "key1"

# assume firstKey has all the minimum entries
# use it as a base to compare all other values to
minD = {}
for (k,v) in myD[firstKey].items():
    minD[k] = v

items = myD.items()

#  find minimum of variable x, then y, then z
for variable in minD:
    print "Finding minimum of " + variable

    for key, dictionary in items:
        keyVal = dictionary[variable]
        if minD[variable] > keyVal:
            minD[variable] = keyVal

print minD # {'y': 420, 'x': 123, 'z': 99}
```